# How to add a user input number to the end of a string to select a specific object

Tags: java

im struggling with abit of java code.

Currently i have 8 rooms

```
    room1 = new Room(1,1);
    room2 = new Room(2,1);
    room3 = new Room(3,1);
    room4 = new Room(4,1);
    room5 = new Room(5,2);
    room6 = new Room(6,2);
    room7 = new Room(7,3);
    room8 = new Room(8,3);
```

Now i need to make it so that the user inputs a number 1 to 8 regarding the room they require, then the system needs to add that number to the prefix room so that i can call methods of the desired room.

I currently have this code to receive the selection

```
roomselect = scan.nextInt();
```

and then this is where i get stuck as im unsure how to add roomselect integer onto the prefix 'room'

thanks

Comment: You need to use an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use arrays:

```
// Create an array of Rooms
Room rooms[] = new Room[8];
// Now, you have a placeholder for 8 rooms
// Know that it are simply placeholders, the rooms are not initialized.
// Each element of the array is initialized to null

// Assigning
rooms[2] = new Room(3, 2); // Initialize the room at index 2 (which is the 3th 
                           // in spoken language)


// Retrieving
int index = 4; // Indices start at 0
Room room4 = rooms[index];

// Or...
rooms[5].doSomething();


// Getting the length
int numberOfRooms = rooms.length;
```

So, to solve your case:

```
int roomselect = scan.nextInt();
Room selectedRoom = rooms[roomselect];
```

Comment: Thank you for this why didnt i think of arrays! Youve saved myself precious time thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you change your code to:

```
List<Room> rooms = new ArrayList<Room>();    
rooms.add(new Room(1,1));
rooms.add(new Room(2,1));
...
```

you can get your specified room with

```
rooms.get(roomselect);
```

Note that the indexes will start at 0 and not at 1.

Answer (score 1):

Store your rooms in an array instead of as separate variables and then access each room by the array index:

```
Room[] rooms = new Room[8];

rooms[roomNumber].doSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Java Collection** is the answer...

```
ArrayList<Room> room = new ArrayList<Room>();

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

for (int i=1 ; i<9 ; i++){

     int r = scan.nextLine();

     if (r<5){

       room.add(new Room(r,1));
   }

    else if ((r>4) && (r<7)){

      room.add(new Room(r,2));
   }

    else if (r>6){

       room.add(new Room(r,3));

   }

}
```